# Need to deploy the ec2 instances in multiple regions with same subnet name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created vpc and subnet with same name in both the regions but Ids of VPC and subnets are different.

Virgina:

VPC Name:kdt
Subnet Name: kdt-private-d

Ohio:

VPC Name:kdt
Subnet Name: kdt-private-d

We Need to deploy the ec2 instance in virgina and ohio at one go

data.tf

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc-id" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt"]
  }

}

data "aws_subnet" "subnetid" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.vpc-id.id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt-private-d"]
  }
}
```

Provider.tf

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = {
            source = "hashicorp/aws"
            #version = "~> 3.0"
        }
    }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1" 

 
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-east-2"
  region = "us-east-2"

}
```

main.tf

```
## Virgina Region

module "ec2-virgina" {

    source          =   "../ec2"
    ami             =   "ami-0230bd60aa4826999" 
    name            =   var.name
    instance_type   =   data.aws_ec2_instance_type.type.id
    subnet_id       =   data.aws_subnet.subnetid.id
    

    providers = {
        aws = "us-east-1"
    }

}

## Ohio Region

module "ec2-ohio" {
    source          =   "../ec2"
    ami             =   "ami-048e636f368eb4567"
    name            =   var.name
    instance_type   =   data.aws_ec2_instance_type.type.id
    subnet_id       =   data.aws_subnet.subnetid.id
    providers = {
        aws = "aws.us-east-2"
    }

}
```

when i ran terraform apply i am getting error that subnet id that fetched from the data.tf is not there in the ohio region.

Since my default region virgina it fetching only virgina subnet id and not ohio subnet id. Please let us know how to pull the subnet ids for both the regions based on the Name of the subnets.

Tried Provider as ohio in module section but its not working:

```
module "ec2-ohio" {
    source          =   "../ec2"
    ami             =   "ami-048e636f368eb4999"
    name            =   var.name
    instance_type   =   data.aws_ec2_instance_type.type.id`your text`
    subnet_id       =   data.aws_subnet.subnetid.id
    providers = {
        aws = "aws.us-east-2"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Data source work the same way as resources - you need to specify the region you are querying the data source from. For this code to work, you need the following:

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc-id" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt"]
  }

}

data "aws_subnet" "subnetid" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.vpc-id.id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt-private-d"]
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "vpc-id-ohio" {
  proivder = aws.us-east-2
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt"]
  }

}

data "aws_subnet" "subnetid-ohio" {
  proivder = aws.us-east-2
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.vpc-id-ohio.id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["kdt-private-d"]
  }
}
```

Then, when calling the module, you don't need to specify an alias for the provider in `us-east-1`, as resources (and data sources) will by default use the one named `aws` if the `provider` argument is not specified. So the second part of the code should be:

```
## Virgina Region

module "ec2-virgina" {
    source          =   "../ec2"
    ami             =   "ami-0230bd60aa4826999" 
    name            =   var.name
    instance_type   =   data.aws_ec2_instance_type.type.id
    subnet_id       =   data.aws_subnet.subnetid.id
    
}

## Ohio Region

module "ec2-ohio" {
    source          =   "../ec2"
    ami             =   "ami-048e636f368eb4567"
    name            =   var.name
    instance_type   =   data.aws_ec2_instance_type.type.id
    subnet_id       =   data.aws_subnet.subnetid-ohio.id
    providers = {
        aws = "aws.us-east-2"
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this one and got the result.

Comment: Hi Marko, Instead of adding multiple data "aws_subnet" each for ohio and virgina. Is it possible to loop the data and pass the subnet id values in the module "ec2-virgina" and module "ec2-ohio". Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: No, you have to define the provider explicitly per resource/data source. If this helped, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow/86979#86979.